# .htaccess using rewritengine to make a php image to png

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a php script what will create an image, but I would like to make that a .png file instead.

Here is an example:

```
http://www.example.com/signature.php?username=Kevin
```

Into this:

```
http://www.example.com/signature.png?username=Kevin
```

I have tried this with the following contents in my .htaccess file, but didn't work.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^signature.png$ signature.php?username=$1 [L]
```

What would I need to change in my .htaccess file to make this work, or is this not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(signature)\.png$ $1.php [L,NC]
```

`QUERY_STRING` will be automatically carried over to target URL.